# Open Twitter Application from Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

Would anyone know the class name to only open twitter application? `intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android");` 
Apparently this does not work.

I know we can open the post link, but thats not what I want. Can anyone help please. 
This is the code for posting.

```
intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android",
        "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? Note it will only work if they already have the twitter app installed. If you only want to open the application(not post a tweet), try changing Intent.ACTION_SEND to Intent.ACTION_VIEW

```
 try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is a tweet");
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        final List<?> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        int len =  activityList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            final ResolveInfo app = (ResolveInfo) activityList.get(i);
            if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
                final ActivityInfo activity=app.activityInfo;
                final ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                intent.setComponent(name);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
  }
    catch(final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("twitter", "no twitter native",e );
    }
```